# Room postpone LiveData events in transaction

Tags: android, transactions, android-room, android-livedata

I'm using the Room database as main source of data in my app. Currently I've encountered an issue. I have this flow in my app:

1. Show data from the database
2. Fetch new data from a back-end
3. Remove old data from the db
4. Insert new data in the db

The problem is in steps 3 and 4. All data shown in the UI is backed by a LiveData object, so when I remove old data from the db the LiveData object notifies the UI that the db is empty, and my UI briefly becomes empty. And as soon as a new data is inserted the UI becomes populated by new data.
Initially, I thought that placing remove and insert operations in one transaction will tell the Room to "postpone" notifications until `setTransactionSuccessful()` method is called. Yet, it doesn't fix the issue.

Does anyone knows how achieve desired behaviour?(except unsubscribing LiveData object).

Comment: 1. What is your desired behaviour ? 2. What is the problem in your step 3 and 4 ? 

Since the LiveData keep observer your data source, when the record is empty, the live data will fire with empty data. When the new data come , it fires the new data. I should be the normal issue.

Comment: @LongRanger
1. When ``database.inTransaction() == true`` - I've expected that LiveData would not emit changes until transaction is done.
2. I would like them to be considered as "one operation", and trigger LiveData only when both of them are completed.

Comment: Yeah I have the exact same issue. I don't want any live data to trigger until the transaction is finished. Did you solve this problem somehow?